# fetching each item inside an array

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, fetch, promise.all

So I'm pretty sure this have something to do with `Promise.all` or something like that but I'm not sure how to do it. will appreciate if someone can help me out with this code.

Note: the array I'm trying to map is an array of objects if that matters

```
const productsArray = this.cartProducts.map(product => 
      fetch(`/api/products/getDetails/${product.clientId}`))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
```

I'm not able to even launch this code but I'm not sure what I should do exactly...

This is my error from visual studio code.

```
property 'then' does not exist on type 'promise<response>[]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) result is promise so you need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const promises = await Promise.all(this.cartProducts.map(product => fetch(`/api/products/getDetails/${product.clientId}`))
const productsArray = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.json()))
```

Comment: thank you this  was exactly what i was looking for! it works great however i am getting a 400 stauts  error before it works... not sure why

Answer (score 0):

William Wang's answer is perfectly good but you may want to use async/await to like this:

```js
const productsArray = this.cartProducts.map(async product => {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/products/getDetails/${product.clientId}`);
      const data = res.json();
      return data;
});
```

It may be simplified with:

```js
const productsArray = this.cartProducts.map(async product => {
      return await fetch(`/api/products/getDetails/${product.clientId}`).json();
});
```

However be aware that this kind of pattern will be more "synchronous" than using a Promise.all pattern, as every product will be fetch only after the previous one is fetched. Promise.all will fetch all the product on parallel.

Comment: async await inside map() doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Is it my snippet ? Or in general ? I've used that pattern a few times and it worked all the way as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Map each item in the array to a fetch call and wrap them around `Promise.all()`.

```js
Promise.all(
  this.cartProducts.map(p =>
    fetch(`/api/products/getDetails/${p.clientId}`).then(res => res.json())
  )
).then(products => console.log(products));
```

#### Explanation

[`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) a.k.a "I promise I'll give you a value in the future". When the time comes, that future value is *resolved* and passed to the callback in `.then(callback)` for further processing. The result of `.then()` is also a `Promise` which means they're chainable.

```js
// returns Promise
fetch('...')
// also returns Promise
fetch('...').then(res => res.json())
// also returns Promise where the next resolved value is undefined
fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(() => undefined)
```

So the code below will return another `Promise` where the resolved value is a parsed Javascript object.

```js
  fetch('...').then(res => res.json())
```

[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) maps each item to the result of the callback and return a new array after all callbacks are executed, in this case an array of `Promise`.

```js
const promises = this.cartProducts.map(p =>
  fetch("...").then(res => res.json())
);
```

After calling map, you will have a list of `Promise` waiting to be resolved. They *do not* contains the actual product value fetched from the server as explained above. But you don't want promises, you want to get an array of the final resolved values.

That's where [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) comes into play. They are the promise version of the `Array.map()` where they 'map' each `Promise` to the resolved value using the `Promise` API.

Because of that `Promise.all()` will resolve yet another new `Promise` after *all* of the individual promises in the `promises` array have been resolved.

```js
// assuming the resolved value is Product

// promises is Promise[]
const promises = this.cartProducts.map(p =>
  fetch("...").then(res => res.json())
);

Promise.all(promises).then(products => {
  // products is Product[]. The actual value we need
  console.log(products)
})
```